# how to connect or load file.dll to matlab?

Tags: matlab, dll, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

I want through matlab tutorial but I did not understand it clearly.

Could anyone can explain to me step by step how to load and call `.dll` functions in matlab?

I tried to use `loadlibrary` function but I get and error, if anyone can tell we where to put the `.dll` file and the `.h` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't do this often, but i usually do something like:

```
fullpathToHeader = 'c:\full\path\to\a\header.h';
fullpathToDll    = 'c:\full\path\to\a\libraty.dll';

loadlibrary(fullpathToDll, fullpathToHeader);
```

Then if that works, you can call library functions as:

```
[outArg1, outArg2, ...] = calllib('library','function',inArg1, inArg2, ...)
```

Answer (score -3):

See the following link, which contains some problems I encountered and overcame, when trying to load a dll into matlab:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/341602